# Remove Processing Instruction (<?xml tags and content) from XML String

Tags: php, regex, xml, string, processing-instruction

I have this tag in a string:

```
<?xml:namespace prefix = o /?>
```

How do I remove that and similar tags from the string with PHP and regex?

I tried:

```
$clean = preg_replace('/<\?xml[^>]+\/>/im', '', $dirty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in that string is a [*Processing Instruction* (PI, see XML 1.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi).

If you want to remove those PIs from a string that you expect to be UTF-8 encoded w/o making use of the PCRE UTF-8 modifier, you can use the following pattern:

```
~
    <\?
    (?: [A-Za-z_:] | [^\x00-\x7F] ) (?: [A-Za-z_:.-] | [^\x00-\x7F] )*
    (?: \?> | \s (?: [^?]* \?+ ) (?: [^>?] [^?]* \?+ )* >)
~x
```

It is a translation from *[a REX expression for XML Processing Instructions](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/REX.html#IV.2)* to a PCRE expression as used in PHP.

A code example:

```
$str = "some string <?xml:namespace prefix = o /?> that is";

$pattern = '~
    <\?
    (?: [A-Za-z_:] | [^\x00-\x7F] ) (?: [A-Za-z_:.-] | [^\x00-\x7F] )*
    (?: \?> | \s (?: [^?]* \?+ ) (?: [^>?] [^?]* \?+ )* >)
~x';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

The output:

```
some string  that is
```

Different to the previous answer given is that this regular expression does ...

- ... take the closing sequence ("`?>`") correctly into account. Especially a "`>`" can be allowed in a processing instruction.
- ... there is no requirement to limit the name of the processing instruction to start with "`xml`" only.
- ... it actually looks for a name as part of the opening sequence.
- ... deals with empty and non-empty processing instructions.

Some notes worth to mention about the limitations:

1. The pattern is intended for shallow parsing. That is, if you yet haven't stripped other tag constructs from the string that could contain text which again could look like such a processing instruction (e.g. a CDATA block or a comment), then the pattern would match wrongly.
2. The pattern matches an *XML Declaration* which starts with "`<?xml`" as well. This can be changed by not looking for XML reserved names after the opening "`<?`" with a negative lookahead like "`(?! [xX][mM][lL] (?: \?> | \s ) )`".

Because of these limitations it's perhaps worth to consider

### Alternatives to Regular Expressions

First of all, it can be much easier to just use PHP's [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) to strip the processing instructions. It will remove other tags and comments, too. This might not be always wanted, it's just really straight forward:

```
strip_tags($str)
```

Much more explicit as both the regular expression and `strip_tags` is using one of the XML parsers that ship with PHP to strip the processing instructions. For example PHP's DOM extension. It can be wrapped in a function to be easily applied on a string:

```
dom_strip_pis($str)
```

Such an exemplary function also works with the XML string you have which is using the reserved name "`xml`" as prefix which is actually not really correct in XML. But the parser won't choke on it:

```
/**
 * remove processing instructions from an XML string
 *
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com>
 *
 * @param string $xml
 * @return string
 */
function dom_strip_pis($str) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $fragment =  $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $saved = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $fragment->    appendXML($str);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);
    foreach($fragment->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node instanceof DOMProcessingInstruction) {
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
    }
    return $doc->saveXML($fragment);
}
```

Using an XML parser as given in the last example won't have you to deal with shallow parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close - notice the '?' at the very end before the closing angle bracket:

```
<?xml:namespace prefix = o /?>
```

To match that as well you will need this:

```
<?php
$clean=preg_replace('/<\?xml[^>]+\/\?>/im', '', $dirty);
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate down-votes when there is an attached comment telling me how to improve my answers in the future. If no comment then your downvote doesn't help the SO community...

Comment: Thank you, I am testing it now. I did not down vote, if it works I vote you up. Thank you for your effort Peter :)